# Electron - Cannot use Google's Speech to Text engine

Tags: node.js, typescript, speech-recognition

I want to link [Google Speech to Text engine](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/) with my microphone.
I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize) page, copied the code to my `renderer.ts` file (uncommented the lines with `const`), but when running - getting the following error, due to line 7 (`const client = new speech.SpeechClient();`):
[image]

And yes, I did try to run both `yarn install --force` (as I'm primarily using Yarn) and `npm rebuild`, as well as `yarn add grpc`, yet the problem still occurs.

`renderer.ts`:

```
const record = require('node-record-lpcm16');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = 'en-US';

const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        languageCode: languageCode,
    },
    interimResults: false, // If you want interim results, set this to true
};

// Create a recognize stream
const recognizeStream = client
    .streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', data =>
        process.stdout.write(
            data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
                ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
                : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
        )
    );

// Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
record
    .start({
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        threshold: 0,
        // Other options, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#options
        verbose: false,
        recordProgram: 'rec', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
        silence: '10.0',
    })
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(recognizeStream);

console.log('Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.');
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you please share your code ?

Comment: Have you tried to install gRPC binary module (as mentioned in error) by yourself?

Comment: @Ahm. I literally copied in the 2nd page that I linked - the 2nd block of code, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Grynets I tried as well with no luck.

Comment: Are you sure it's relevant? The repository is about the integration between Electron, Go and gRPC. I'm not programming in Go

Comment: on electron and cloud speech - https://github.com/mattcollier/electron-speech-recognition

Comment: also it looks like you have spaces in the path to your grpc lib  .. those need to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved my problem is the combination of a few sources.

First, installing [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node) (thanks to [murgatroid99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159388) and [Nicolas Noble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2444610)):

```
npm rebuild grpc --runtime=electron --target=4.0.3
```

I assume this installs the `gRPC` binaries so I can use them on `Electron 4.0.3` (not the latest because it seems that it doesn't work on the latest)
Though since it just installs `gRPC`, I still need to install `Electron` separately, so:

```
yarn add -D electron@4.0.3
```

If you want to keep it in one line:

```
npm rebuild grpc --runtime=electron --target=4.0.3 && yarn add -D electron@4.0.3
```

Then I received [this](https://i.imgur.com/DddQPWk.png) error and Googled it, though didn't find a clear answer.
Then I realized, thanks to [this article](https://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=chandong83&logNo=221425183805&categoryNo=65&parentCategoryNo=0&viewDate=&currentPage=1&postListTopCurrentPage=1&from=postView) (translated to English), that the module [node-record-lpcm16](https://github.com/gillesdemey/node-record-lpcm16) was just being used as a bridge from my software to [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net).
So in fact, this error is just about not being able to use the `sox` program from Command Line (can't spawn a process), at least not purely based on just typing `sox` (I could on CMD, but for some reason my application couldn't).
Hence I:

1) Changed `recordProgram: 'rec'` to `recordProgram: 'sox'` (`renderer.ts`)
2) Entered `node_modules\node-record-lpcm16\index.js`
3) Changed

```
case 'sox':
  var cmd = 'sox';
  var cmdArgs = [
    '-q',                     // show no progress
    '-t', 'waveaudio',        // audio type
    '-d',                     // use default recording device
    '-r', options.sampleRate, // sample rate
    '-c', options.channels,   // channels
    '-e', 'signed-integer',   // sample encoding
    '-b', '16',               // precision (bits)
    '-',                      // pipe
    // end on silence
    'silence', '1', '0.1', options.thresholdStart || options.threshold + '%',
    '1', options.silence, options.thresholdEnd || options.threshold + '%'
  ];
  break
```

to

```
case 'sox':
  var cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sox-14-4-2\\sox.exe';
  var cmdArgs = [ // ^ SPECIFYING FULL PATH
    '-q',                     // show no progress
    '-t', 'waveaudio',        // audio type
    '-d',                     // use default recording device
    '-r', options.sampleRate, // sample rate
    '-c', options.channels,   // channels
    '-e', 'signed-integer',   // sample encoding
    '-b', '16',               // precision (bits)
    '-',                      // pipe
    // end on silence
    'silence', '1', '0.1', options.thresholdStart || options.threshold + '%',
    '1', options.silence, options.thresholdEnd || options.threshold + '%'
  ];
  break
```

Then, turns out that without adding an extra bit that's mentioned in the aforementioned article,, recording the microphone wouldn't work, so:

```
case 'sox':
  var cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sox-14-4-2\\sox.exe';
  var cmdArgs = [
    '-q',                     // show no progress
    '-t', 'waveaudio',        // audio type
    '-d',                     // use default recording device
    '-r', options.sampleRate, // sample rate
    '-c', options.channels,   // channels
    '-e', 'signed-integer',   // sample encoding
    '-t', 'raw', // Added
    '-b', '16',               // precision (bits)
    '-',                      // pipe
    // end on silence
    'silence', '1', '0.1', options.thresholdStart || options.threshold + '%',
    '1', options.silence, options.thresholdEnd || options.threshold + '%'
  ];
  break
```

If you're getting Google Cloud credential authentication issues, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043611)

And these resolved my problems of being able to record!

Then I had a problem that Google limits the audio stream to 65 seconds, so via the  stack trace lines, I traced down the lines that caused the problem & commented those lines, until I reached the 2nd possible output in `renderer.ts` (output `Reached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C`), so I just wrapped the variable & record functions inside a function and called the function recursively, like so:

```
function startRecording() {
    // Create a recognize stream
    const recognizeStream = client
        .streamingRecognize(request)
        .on('error', console.error)
        .on('data', data => {
            if (data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]) {
                console.log(`Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`);
            } else {
                console.log(`\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`);
                startRecording();
            }
        });

    // Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
    record
        .start({
            sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
            threshold: 0,
            // Other options, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#options
            verbose: false,
            recordProgram: 'sox', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
            silence: '10.0',
        })
        .on('error', console.error)
        .pipe(recognizeStream);
}

startRecording();
```

And this solution seems to solve that problem!

Comment: This solution was only relevant at the time. These days, you'll need to find a different solution that's using the latest version of Electron (11.1.1 by the time of commenting), and the aforementioned `node-record-lpcm16`'s `index.js` has a modern JS code, thus my solution is no longer relevant for today.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this library on Electron you have to add extra installation arguments to specifically install for Electron. Electron has generic instructions for [using native Node modules](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules).

For gRPC in particular, with the version of Electron you have, you should be able to get it by running

```
npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=4.0.0
```

---

A word of warning for Electron 4 in particular: Due to a breaking change introduced in Electron 4.0.4, grpc will not work with that version. It will still work with previous versions of Electron 4.

Comment: That's the breaking change in Electron 4.0.4 I warned about in my last paragraph. As I said, the library will not work with that specific version.

Comment: So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Rollback to electron 4.0.3 in your package.json by using neither ^ or ~ as a marker.

Comment: After iteratively attempting to install `grpc` and then attempting to install `electron` specifically in version `4.0.3`, I had successfully received a different error related to Google Cloud Authentication. After [resolving this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043611), my only error is [this](https://i.imgur.com/DddQPWk.png)