# "Could not load default credentials" google cloud secrets manager - use CLI authorized user

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-secret-manager, gcloud-cli

I would like to have my `nodeJS` application authenticate itself locally with my `IAM` credentials, however when I run the basic `secrets manager` function below:

```js
// config/secret_manager.js
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager')

const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient()

async function getSecret(name) {
  const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({ name })
  const secretValue = JSON.parse(version.payload.data.toString())

  return secretValue
}

module.exports = getSecret
```

I receive the error:

> Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
> at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use my `CLI` login credentials locally, **any ideas**?

(I don't want to use a JSON service account config)

Comment: Since you tagged `Node.js`, you probably should use a service account and not user credentials. For debugging, user credentials can be used, but are not recommended for production scenarios. When running code on a Google compute service, the credentials from metadata should be used. Update your question with more details on the environment.

Comment: @JohnHanley in CloudRun would this same function not grab what ever service account is available?

Comment: The code in your question will fetch the credentials from metadata. Your answer would not work in Cloud Run. A key point is to not use user credentials where a service account should be used which is almost always the case for one of the compute services. The SDKs will print a warning, you will be quota limited, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you're authenticated with the `gcloud` `CLI` *you need to set the default application login*. This is solved by running `gcloud auth application-default login`

Source: [Could not load the default credentials? (Node.js Google Compute Engine tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043611/could-not-load-the-default-credentials-node-js-google-compute-engine-tutorial#answer-42059661)