# How to run gcloud if Google Cloud SDK if my project is on another drive?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm building an API with Google Cloud functions and I had the same issue as the guy from this post: [Could not load the default credentials? (Node.js Google Compute Engine tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043611/could-not-load-the-default-credentials-node-js-google-compute-engine-tutorial)

When trying to use my API, I received this error:

`Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.`

So I went on and followed the steps suggested in the question I mentioned. I downloaded the gcloud SDK, installed it, and at the end of the installation wizard there is an option to run the google cloud cli immediately.

I ran it successfully and logged in properly, now any time I open the **command prompt** I can use the gcloud command without a problem.

Mi issue is the following. I'm running my commands in VSCode bash terminal and I get an error saying that the **gcloud command is not found**.

My project is in my D: drive, and the SDK is on C:, which I believe is the reason why the gcloud command is not recognized when I attempt to use it.

Should/can I install the Google Cloud SDK in my D: drive and use it there, or should I move my project to the C: drive?

I read somewhere that this might be a problem with the bash terminal, but I tried running it from command prompt in VSCode and I get the same error, so I guess it's got nothing to do with it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Neither. Set up the PATH environment for Visual Studio Code so that it knows how to find the CLI.

Comment: Oh, how did I not think of that. I'll try that right now, thanks.